# Adding string variable in view causes error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 @model  abc
 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "abc view";
   string xyz = "";
 }
```

This above code throws an error:

> at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>   at ......

Now if I remove

```
 string xyz = "";
```

from view, it's not giving me any error. And error exists only in my hosting environment, it's running fine in local.

Please help me.

I tried enabling view build, it is not helping

```
   <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Comment: instead of `string xyz = ""`, can you try `var xyz = " "`

Comment: You need to show us the **actual, complete ERROR message** - not just parts of the stack trace .....